# p5.js eye tracking using ml5 library

Tags: p5.js, ml5.js

im trying to make an intractive p5js piece of eye tracking and multiplying the eye on the screen.
I have made a demo of the concept expect that I didn't make it to track only the eye, its tracking the whole face.
I took the expample code of ml5 library and changed it
the example code: https://editor.p5js.org/ml5/sketches/XFnGW770Y

and this is my code
https://editor.p5js.org/trzcrzamvs/sketches/FJ1Ej88jO

I didn't found a way to use the tracking of the eyes the same way I used the outer box of the face

Comment: Repost of deleted post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446689/eye-tracking-using-p5js-and-ml5-and-cropping-the-img-to-the-eye?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Your code seems to be working, the face and eyes are tracked. But then you redraw the whole face a couple of times, why is that? What exactly is not working?